# mysql - How to improve case when performance?

Tags: mysql

I've this query-

```
SELECT * FROM alerts a 
INNER JOIN alerts_account aa ON a.alert_id=aa.alert_id 
WHERE aa.account_id=638 
AND a.type IN(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17) 
AND CASE WHEN (type = 11 OR type = 13 OR type = 16 OR type = 17) 
THEN (is_acknowledged = 0) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, utc_timestamp()) <= 4) 
ELSE 1=1 
END order by a.alert_id desc limit 10
```

My table have millions of entries and its the `TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, utc_timestamp())` that's slowing down the query? It takes more than 10 seconds. How can I improve the performance in this case. Should I even use CASE WHEN here?

EDIT:

alerts

```
alert_id | type | time                | details| patient_account_id
1        | 1    | 2014-10-22 05:43:45 | 2015   | 234
2        | 5    | 2014-10-22 06:21:23 | 2014   | 345
3        | 12   | 2014-10-22 14:30:23 | 2016   | 456
```

alert_account

```
alerts_account_id | alert_id |account_id| is_poped_up| is_acknowledged
1                 | 1        |234       | 0          | 0
2                 | 2        |345       | 1          | 1
3                 | 3        |456       | 1          | 1
```

alerts

[image: alerts]

alerts_account

[image: alerts_account]

Comment: Remove your case when, case when in where clause is not recommeded.

Comment: show both table schema with indexes and alerts table count of rows whith condition type in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17) and alerts_account table row count with condition account_id=638...

Comment: @ZafarMalik please see my edit

Comment: @Dr.Stitch What else can I use?

Comment: @HeisenBerg : You have posted some sample data but I want to check table schema along with indexes and also both tables count total count and count with given conditions.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Have posted schema. Can't post count because I've only access to my local DB at the moment. It's in the live server's DB that I've problem. It has millions of rows..

Comment: from this CASE WHEN (type = 11 OR type = 13 OR type = 16 OR type = 17) 
THEN (is_acknowledged = 0) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, utc_timestamp()) <= 4) 
ELSE 1=1 to this (((type = 11 OR type = 13 OR type = 16 OR type = 17) AND ((is_acknowledged = 0) AND (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, time, utc_timestamp()) <= 4))) OR 1 = 1)

Comment: @Dr.Stitch It doesn't even give me the same results.

Comment: kindly replace or 1=1 to OR (type <> 11 AND type <> 13 AND type <> 16 AND type <> 17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create index as per below and check performance-

```
alter table alerts_account add index idx_alert_id(alert_id);
```

You get sufficient performance by this further provide me count as I asked to gain more performance.

Even most accurate index we can have only after getting desired count but after seeing your query it seems that mostly data is filtered by account_id field, so you can create final index as per below-

```
alter table alerts_account add index idx_alert_id(alert_id), add index idx_account_id(account_id);
```

Comment: no, index are required on alert_account table as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Sorry, for a moment. I got the names mixed up. I deleted my comment. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: sorry that I forgot to accept your answer... thanks a lot mate